# ¿Cómo cargar los datos JSON en el select después de agregar una nueva fila dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario y un campo `select` llamado `Services`, el mismo al cargar la Web obtiene los datos en JSON como resultado de una consulta `ajax` a la Base de datos.

Ahora requiero que además cuando le doy a agregar una nueva fila dinámicamente, se carguen los datos en el `select` services pero el Javascript está escrito para que lo haga al cargar la página, no sé como indicarle que al agregar la nueva fila haga la consulta `ajax`.

Así agrego la nueva fila:

```
newRow: function () {
    jQuery(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td><div class="delete-btn"><input class="form-control qty" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" value="1" type="text" readonly="readonly"><a class=' + $.opt.delete.substring(1) + ' href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="col-4"><select class="form-control" name="service_id[]" id="service_id" onchange=\'changePrice();\'></select></td></tr>');

    if (jQuery($.opt.delete).length > 0) {
        jQuery($.opt.delete).show();
    }

    return 1;
},
```

Mi consulta ajax:

```
<script>

  let datos = '';

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ route('options') }}",
      data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
      success: function(data) {
        datos = $.parseJSON(data);
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        console.log(error); 
      }
                               
    });  
    
  });                                  
</script>
```

Nota: funciona bien para la primera fila que no se agrega dinámicamente, en la imagen es la remarcada en color rojo (1), y la que agrego dinámicamente es la remarcada en color naranja (2) y allí no logro cargar los datos en el select de la consulta ajax, está definida para funcionar al terminar de cargar la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador:

```
public function options()
{
    $services = Service::all();

    if (!$services->isEmpty()) {

        foreach ($services as $service) {
            $elements[] = array($service->price);  
        }

        $options = json_encode($elements);
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. ¿De dónde deberían venir los datos de la segunda fila? ¿Del servidor? Entonces, en el bloque que crea la nueva fila deberás lanzar otra petición Ajax para que te busque los que serían los nuevos datos con los que deberá llenarse la nueva fila.

Comment: Con lo que me dices se me ocurrió algo que no me está funcionando del todo, pero igual me gustaría conocer como hacer esa petición desde la nueva fila como lo estás pensando, yo lo que hice (Sé que no es lo mejor por repetir código) copiar la funcion del llamado al ajax, además de hacer el llamado al ajax al cargar la web, que se ejecute cuando el usuario haga click en el botón add item `$("#addRow").click(function(){ el código aquí, que está en la descripción });` en la consola cada vez que hago clic trae el array, pero no me carga el select.

Comment: El problema que yo veo es que nunca llenas el select, en tu evento `newRow` agregas un select, pero va vació, yo te recomiendo que generes el row, td, inputs y select cada uno en una variable y luego los añadas con apend, y asi tienes el control de tu elemento para agregar los options.

Comment: No es mala idea reutilizar código, en efecto, tú puedes tener una función dedicada a hacer la petición Ajax en caso de que necesites hacerla varias veces, y pasarle en cada caso los parámetros cambiantes de la misma (URL, datos, tipo de petición, etc). Pero lo que no queda claro aún es la acción que debe ejecutar el click del botón para crear esa segunda o esa `N` fila, supongo que sería tomar datos de alguna parte para mandar a buscar algo al servidor en base a esos datos ¿? Es un aspecto importante de tu código que no explicas en ningún momento.

Comment: Okey, gracias... Actualicé la pregunta y agregué el controlador al cual llama el ajax, lo que requiero es hacer una consulta y completar las opciones del select con esos resultados. Funciona para la primera fila que la tengo apenas carga la Web, a partir de la segunda fila (que se llama dinámicamente) no cargan los datos en las opciones. Ahora con tu ayuda me está mostrando el array de la consulta en la consola, pero no carga el select.

Comment: El problema al parecer es del html incrustado en el Jquery para agregar la fila, estoy copiando y pegando los datos de la primera fila y funciona, con el código html del Jquery no.

Comment: Si copias y pegas el código del html te va a funcionar por que ese tiene la información de los options,  ¿Como llenas el primer registro?.

Comment: Sí, estaba funcionando si copiaba y pegaba el código html, pero con tantos cambios ya estoy haciendo algo nuevo, creo que haré una pregunta nueva cuando esté más cerca.

Comment: Ya al darle clic en `Add item` los agrega, pero en el primer select